# The Api is missing records, I'm using Moonge with express Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm fetching the data from the API and the API is showing me different records on reloads. Somethings it shows me the correct data and sometimes misses the records. When I hit the API URL in postman it works fine for me.

The API Url I'm using: **https://backend.websouls.com/api/currencies/dump** It's a **POST** request with the body for example like this.

[image: Api url Look like this.]

The issue I'm facing is very critical for me.

[image: That's the payload that I'm sending on front side]

[image: Thats my Api url]

[image: And that's my response]

As you can see in above 3 images that I have attached above. I'm sending the request for 4 Pids data and the API is giving me only 2 records.

If anyone has any idea how to fix this issue kindly help me Thank you!

I tried to console the pids in the backend to check the body gets the pids properly and it's working fine, also I use that pids array in request query to check the API behavior but same behavior.

The Function on the backend where I fetch the records from mongoose is given bellow.

```
exports.getPackages = async function (req, res) {
  const pids = req.query.p_id;
  let newObject = [];

  let obj = {};
  for (i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) {
    let cr = [];
    const package = await priceModel
      .find({ pid: pids[i] })
      .select({ pro_config_options: 0 });
    //res.json(package);
    const packageFeatures = await featuresModel
      .find({ pid: pids[i] })
      .select({ pid: 0 });
    //res.json(packageFeatures);
    for (j = 0; j < package.length; j++) {
      let ccr = {
        currency: package[j].currency,
        annually: package[j].annually,
        biennially: package[j].biennially,
        triennially: package[j].triennially,
        monthly: package[j].monthly,
        quarterly: package[j].quarterly,
        semiannually: package[j].semiannually,
        qsetupfee: package[j].qsetupfee,
        ssetupfee: package[j].ssetupfee,
        asetupfee: package[j].asetupfee,
        bsetupfee: package[j].bsetupfee,
        tsetupfee: package[j].tsetupfee,
      };
      cr.push(ccr);
    }

    obj = {
      id: package[0]._id,
      pid: package[0].pid,
      name: package[0].name,
      title: package[0].title,
      tid: "",
      fname: package[0].fname,
      currency: cr,
      addons: [],
      freedomain: [],
      packageFeatures,
      addonids: package[0].addonids,
    };
    // res.json(obj);
    newObject.push(obj);
    //package.push(newObject);
  }
  res.json(newObject);
};
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing the `p_id` parameter in the body so you should retrieve it from there: `const pids = req.body.p_id;`. Also, don't forget to initialize the loop index: `for (let i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) { ... }`

Comment: oh I forgot to replace the  req.query.p_id to  req.body.p_id.. Letme try the initializing the loop index I hope it works.